# Javascript random number between two digits

Tags: javascript, random

I want to generate a valid number between 200 and 450. Here is my snippet of code.

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 450) + 200
```

Sometimetimes its 568 or any number not in the range i would want it to be. Can anybode give me a hint how to solve it please?

Comment: Note the answer by Francisc in the duplicate.

Comment: if you add 200, then you really want a seed under 250 to arrive at 450